# Responsive navigation bar issue with logo shifting

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want the logo to shift to the middle when using devices like smartphones and hide the login and register button.

I am successful in hiding the buttons but I am failing to shift the logo. Here is the code.

```html
<nav class="px-md-5 p-3 py-lg-3 py-5 bg-dark text-white d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <div class="d-flex alignment ">
    <h1>LOGO</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between ">
    <a href="" class="btn border-white text-white mr-3 d-sm-none d-none d-md-none d-lg-block font_login">LOGIN</a>
    <a href="" class="btn border-white text-white d-sm-none d-none d-md-none d-lg-block">Register</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Where's the associated CSS/JS? By itself this code won't change responsively to the screen dimensions or pixel density  Are you using a framework, if so which one?

Comment: Yeah i am using codeigniter as a framework. I didnot use any css and js.

Comment: Codeigniter is a server side framework. What is the client side framework?

Comment: I am not using any client side frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code in css:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
.alignment{
margin:0 auto;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on following using media query for certain device width you can achieve this.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .d-flex {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="px-md-5 p-3 py-lg-3 py-5 bg-dark text-white d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <div class="d-flex alignment ">
    <h1>LOGO</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between ">
    <a href="" class="btn border-white text-white mr-3 d-sm-none d-none d-md-none d-lg-block font_login">LOGIN</a>
    <a href="" class="btn border-white text-white d-sm-none d-none d-md-none d-lg-block">Register</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```